# Typescript: question sign after type annotation in assignment expression (nullable type?)

Tags: typescript

Today I discovered I can do this:

```ts
let foo: string? // foo now has type string | null
```

What's that? I cannot find a reference of it in the TS handbook. Can someone point to it?

Another (not less important though) question is: why the heck it produces `string | null` and not `string | undefined`? Because the latter would be much more useful since a declared (but not initialized) variable usually has type `undefined`. This is even more confusing, given that question sign in interfaces give us `... | undefined` type.

P.S. My TS version is 3.4.3

UPD. It seems it's a bug. Worked only if followed by an if statement:

```ts
let foo: string?
if(1) {

}
```

Then, again, ok it's a bug, but why it produced `string | null`?

Comment: Are you sure about this ? I get an error `'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` Maybe  you have a definition of `string` somewhere ? https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/DYUwLgBAZg9jEF4IGcwCcCWA7A5gfgCgg

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Titian Hi! And sorry, I had a typo (`=` instead of `:`) and I fixed it shortly after...

Comment: Still get an error https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/DYUwLgBAZg9jBcEDOYBOBLAdgcwPwG4AoIA

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I guess it is a TS 3.4.something thing. Works on 3.4.3

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Hmm. I was wrong, I think it's a bug, works only if there is an if statement after the question sign..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir BTW do you know why there is not still a syntax like `string?` as a shortcut to `string | undefined`? Because of interference with conditional types?

Comment: I don't know. `string | undefined` is the only option ..or define a custom type alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is intended to support some version of [JSDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc) nullable-type (that is, `| null`) notation for using [TypeScript to check JavaScript files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html).  If you start using JSDoc syntax in a TypeScript file, I'd expect to see an error... which is what I see in [the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=let%20foo%3A%20string%3F%3B%20%2F%2F%20error!%0D%0A%2F%2F%20JSDoc%20types%20can%20only%20be%20used%20inside%20documentation%20comments.%0D%0A%0D%0A):

```
let foo: string?; // error!
// JSDoc types can only be used inside documentation comments.
```

If you're using that notation in a TypeScript file and not seeing an error, I'd consider that to be a bug (or maybe you have some interesting compiler options set).

---

I say "some version" because the [official JSDoc way](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html) of annotating types as nullable is to use `?` as a *prefix* operator, not as a *postfix* operator.  That is, JSDoc says to use `@type {?string}` instead of `@type {string?}`.

Apparently, Google's [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) unofficially [supports postfix-`?`](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1532#issuecomment-489466852), and I guess [TypeScript does too](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1532#issuecomment-480336365).  But this doesn't conform to the official JSDoc standard, and might even end up [being removed from TS](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1532#issuecomment-490180192).  So I wouldn't rely on it sticking around even if you are using JSDoc type comments in your code.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: I have received a (non-official) response in my github [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31390), this seems to be a pretty old [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7426) and from what I learned this is an implemented but not documented yet feature of nullable type. They have chosen `string | null` instead of `string | undefined` to be produced by `string?` type. Also, semicolon is required almost always after the question sign (probably to avoid interference with conditional types syntax)

Comment: There may be such a feature request, but this behavior is not implemented for TS files, but for JS files being checked by TS, using JSDoc.  Are you not getting a “JSDoc” related error message when you use this syntax in your code?  The implementer of this feature talks about this very issue [here](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1532#issuecomment-480336365).  I’d be happy to remove this answer if you can demonstrate that it isn’t correct, but I’m pretty sure that it is.

Comment: I hate this! I didn't have the JSDoc message you mentioned at the time when I was asking this question, and now I have! I guess my compiler for some reason failed to produce that message at the time.. Maybe because I usually torture the compiler with the weirdest types and keep the editing sessions for days, so it got buggy.. Your answer seems true now..

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is [this feature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7426) being implemented and it requires `;` after `?` to work properly in all cases.